# Changing the title of an openened p:dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

is it possible using PrimeFaces EL to update the title of an opened dialog without updating its content.

My Solutions so far is reopening the dialog and loading its new content. Tried to set the title on server side but couldn't also manage to refresh just the title.

Any hints? Thanks in advance.

Problem is that a button within the dialog is setting up the title. When I do this and update the whole dialog, the dialog will be closed.

Comment: Please read [ask] and improve your question

Comment: @YagamiLight Updating the title of an "opened dialog". I know how to update the title of an unopened dialog.

Comment: @Kukeltje I don't know how to improve this question... With code?

Comment: Yes, with what you tried

Comment: EL is evaluated at server side while rendering a page(fragment). So any EL result has to update your dialog and will close it. I think you have to use javascript.

Comment: @Holger That was exactly my question. Whether it's possible without javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the header facet of p:dialog, insert h:outputText with the title and an id and update only the h:outputText component.

Comment: Yeah nice solution. I will try that.

Comment: Yeah this worked. Can't believe how simple the solution was :D Thanks!